# Weka classify an instance

Tags: java, weka

I try to classify an instance having an arff file as trained data.
The problem is that when I try to create the new Instance I get the exception:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Here is the simple code for creating the new Instance:

```
Instance instance = new Instance(2);
instance.setValue(new Attribute("attr1"), 1);
instance.setValue(new Attribute("attr2"), 1);
```

The exception occurs when I call the setValue method.

Any help please?

Update after Marcin's response

I use weka 3.6.11.
If I use the attributes from the training data, I get another exception when I try to classify the new Instance. For example, if I use

```
 Instance newInstance = new Instance(instances.numAttributes());
 for (int i = 0; i < instances.numAttributes(); i++) {

    Attribute attr = instances.attribute(i);
    newInstance.setValue(attr, 0);
 }

 classifier.classifyInstance(newInstance));
```

I get the exception 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Instance has no dataset assigned!!
at the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of weka do you use? I think you can't instantiate `Instance`, because it is an interface. Moreover, when you create new Attribute with: `new Attribute("attr1")` it gets `-1` as an attribute index. If you have your training `Instances` from arff file, use attribute from them when you create a new `Instance`.

[Create a new weka Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334494/create-a-new-weka-instance)

http://weka.wikispaces.com/Programmatic+Use

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited the initial post with the new exception I get

Comment: invoke `setDataset` method on your new instance, with `instances` as an argument

Comment: @loubas Please don't do that. One question, one answer. Post a new question to your new problem.